# Узнать тип оперативной памяти

Tags: windows-10

Не удается найти информацию по своей озу, что за тип используется. Какой ddr?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал так и так, нигде нету.

Как мне узнать это?

Судя по скриншетам, сколько гнезд доступно и какое количество занято о озу?

Второй вопрос, почему не отображаться инфа по скорости, использованию гнезд?

Comment: В консоли правильно смотрите, но не то значение. `SMBIOSMemoryType` - даст цифру типа, которую можете [глянуть](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory#:~:text=Type%20of%20physical%20memory.%20This%20is%20a%20CIM%20value%20that%20is%20mapped%20to%20the%20SMBIOS%20value.%20The%20SMBIOSMemoryType%20property%20contains%20the%20raw%20SMBIOS%20memory%20type.) в документации. 20 - DDR, 21 - DDR2, 24 - DDR3, 26 - DDR4, и т.д.  Ну и [в помощь](https://msreview.net/windows-10/3556-kak-poluchit-polnye-specifikacii-pamjati-vashego-kompjutera-na-windows-10.html).

Comment: Спс, сработало)